# How add item name with URL in EditForm?

Tags: custom-form, display-form

Maybe someone know how add item name with link in EditForm, like it is in DispForm?

Image of what I need to do:

[image]

(if the image isn't visible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqxQU.jpg)

Comment: You're editing the file's metadata. Why would you want the file name to be a link in this situation? What would be the purpose? What would be the benefit?

Answer (score 1):

I normally hate "Why" answers, but here goes: WHY? The Edit Form is for modifying the properties of a list item, or a library item (document). The Display Form is for showing (read-only) the properties of a list/library item. If a user is looking at the item properties in read mode, they can click the link and get the document. If the user is in edit mode, they are changing the properties of the item. It would be counter-intuitive to expect to open the document while you are editing the properties. Why is the link from the display form insufficient?

I am sincerely curious as to the reason for this requirement.

Comment: +1 +2 +3!! The link to open the document is not relevant when editing the document properties. Step back and think about it, folks! You're just editing the file's metadata. Why would you even WANT a link to open that same file? What is the business process? An XSLT List View Web Part will show the "Name" as the column with the ECB (Edit Control Block), but that can be changed easily with SharePoint Desingner. The point is: that change happens in the **List View Web Part**, and NOT in the properties of the uploaded file. SharePoint 101.

Answer (score 0):

The Title field is single line text field and it does not allow HTML. Even if you try to add, SharePoint will display it as-is (html encoded). It cannot be done.

Comment: So maybe here is some workaround how add ItemName to editForm which will have link directly to document?

Comment: The question is about displaying the file name, not about making the title a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind, neither of which is ideal or pleasant

- Inject Javascript into your master page via some mechanism (Custom
  master page, delegate, whatever) that detects the edit page and
  injects HTML into the page to make a linkable title field
- a [custom field control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679964.aspx) but those are definitely not for the
  timid and require a fair amount of work to get working properly

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link, may be this might help:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/data-view-web-part-the-basics-add-a-hyperlink.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I see a link in the field of DispForm

[image]

only when this field is lookup field to another one.
And when that another one has more than one value then in EditForm I see a drop down list

[image]

and if it has only one value there then it is like on you screenshot.

Meanwhile I do not see any sense in having a link in EditForm... it is just a rendering feature, generated dynamically through XSLT transformation by Sharepoint server, not the content.

You can observe it **Title URL** textbox under **Advanced** section in **Web Part Properties** of **DispForm**

[image]

but copy-pasting the same link manually into corresponding textbox of webpart properties of EditForm will not change the existing rendering of lookup field in EditForm

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint designer open the form Edit.aspx form and Display.aspx forms.

From Display.aspx copy the textfield(Variable name) id, I mean to say the way it is getting displayed and paste inside the edit.aspx form text box of the respective field.

For example: in Disp.aspx find "Name" field and the value in next  , copy that variable and paste it in editform.

I have implemented the same thing in past and it was worked with this kind of trick.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for having the hyperlink or even the text equivalent is this: working with SPOnline we have a library that exceeds the list item threshold, therefore we are limited in what we can do out of the box.  Users on upload get to the editform.aspx page which does not have the document link.  They are then supposed to copy the document link and paste into another system.  With exceeding the list threshold we were forced to use search query web part.  SP online search can take some time before they see the refreshed search results with the new document they just uploaded which does have the link